# v-bind:class data bind doesn't set value in method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I’m trying to bind a width to a div where the width is equal to a data attribute. The value of the data attribute is changing from 0 to 100, but the width of div isn’t changing.
Can someone tell me why?

```
    <div class="bar" :style="{ width: percentage + '%' }"></div>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        data() {
            return {
                 percentage: 0,
                 total: 43,
                 downloaded: 0
            }
        },
    methods: {
            loadData() {
                var _this = this;
                this.toggleLoading();
                var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
                    if (_this.downloaded == _this.total) clearInterval(interval); 

                    _this.downloaded++;
                    _this.percentage = Math.floor(_this.downloaded / _this.total * 100) + ' %';
                }, 
                100);
            },
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatening `'%'` twice:

```
:style="{ width: percentage + '%' }"
```

and

```
_this.percentage = Math.floor(_this.downloaded / _this.total * 100) + ' %'
```

Do it only in one place and it will work fine.

[Simplified JSFiddle concatening `'%'` in style only](https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/8q6wq952/)

Answer (score 0):

you have mention percentage as 0 may be thats why its not changing the width